# Filter only normal users not staff or superusers in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want get only normal users not staff or superusers, how can i add option to this code

```
users = User.objects.filter()
```

thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
User.objects.filter(is_superuser=False, is_staff=False)
```

you can further filter to *active* users with:

```
User.objects.filter(is_superuser=False, is_staff=False, is_active=True)
```